# How do I handle an HTML button being pressed in a web browser object in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, events, vb.net-2010

VB.NET rookie here,

Is there any way to handle an HTML object being clicked inside of a web browser control? The closest I've managed to get is with a mouse-down event handler for the browser which writes the position of the mouse, but I have no way getting information about what html object was clicked.

```
Private Sub myWB_mouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As HtmlElementEventArgs)
    If e.MouseButtonsPressed = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
        'mousedown event
        Debug.WriteLine(e.ClientMousePosition)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Parse the Events of the [HtmlElement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement(v=vs.110).aspx) object. [HtmlDocument.Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.body%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) is one `HtmlElement` (it can be tricky, though). Update the question when you find the next (apparently) odd behaviour.

Comment: If you have any further questions or issues regarding this or my implementation, just let me know in a comment on my answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the coordinates of the click you can use [**`HtmlDocument.GetElementFromPoint()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.getelementfrompoint(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the element at the point of the click.

You can then check the element's [**`TagName` property**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.tagname(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine the type of the element that was clicked, namely if it's a `<button>` or an `<input>` element. If the latter, you also need to check [**`GetAttribute("type")`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.getattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) to determine if the type of the input element is `submit`, which means it is a button.

```
If myWB.Document IsNot Nothing AndAlso e.MouseButtonsPressed = Windows.Forms.MouseButtons.Left Then
    Dim ClickedElement As HtmlElement = myWB.Document.GetElementFromPoint(e.ClientMousePosition)

    If ClickedElement IsNot Nothing AndAlso _
        (ClickedElement.TagName.Equals("button", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) OrElse _
         (ClickedElement.TagName.Equals("input", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) AndAlso ClickedElement.GetAttribute("type").Equals("submit", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))) Then

        'ClickedElement was either a <button> or an <input type="submit">. Do something...

    End If
End If
```